# Why it is an error on compiler but run at Spark-shell?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The command

```
println(  sql( "SELECT date_format(now(),'yyyyMMdd')" ).as[String].first )
```

is working fine on Spark-shell (using Spark v2.2), but the line

```
 val databaseNow = spark.sql( "SELECT date_format(now(),'yyyyMMdd')" ).as[String].first
```

not compile. I try many import variations and problem persist. I try syntax variations as `df.first.toString` but it is not a solution (`[x]` is not `x`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include the included encoders like :

```
val spark: SparkSession =
  SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("test")
    .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val databaseNow = spark.sql( "SELECT date_format(now(),'yyyyMMdd')" ).as[String].first
```

Comment: There are many ways or only one "good practice" to implicits lib? I see also   `import spark.implicits._` or `val sqlContext= new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc); import sqlContext.implicits._` ... Can I use in any compiler (using IntelliJ) your `import spark.implicits._`?  ...All this is confuse for me, I am not from Java.

Comment: **ERROR**, IntelliJ say  "Cannot resolve symbol spark". Them I used `import org.apache.spark.implicits._`  but say "Cannot resolve symbol spark". [This link](https://medium.com/@mrpowers/manually-creating-spark-dataframes-b14dae906393) say *"The import spark.implicits._ statement can only be run inside of class definitions when the Spark Session is available"*.

Comment: The implicits._ that you import are inside the SparkSession class so you must create an instance and then import the all the instances defined in the implicits object.

Comment: Strange, but running: I am using into the *main*, `object MyObj { def main() = { ...  import spark.implicits._ ; val databaseNow = spark.sql( "..." ).as[String].first; ... }`. So, **can't  use** `import spark.implicits._` with all other imports in the begin of the scala script, **must use** on context imedatly before its use ... Is it?

Comment: In Scala you can use the clause import inside an object, it can be used everywhere. And this is something very useful when you work with implicits and create different contexts, for example when you work with type classes.